# How to start LDAP service in linux using ANT task

Tags: linux, ant

In linux, I am able to start LDAP serice like this

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ldap start
```

now I want to do this using ANT:

```
<target name="ldap-service-start" description="Start LDAP service">
          <exec executable="ldap" osfamily="unix" dir="/etc/init.d">
           <arg line="start"/>
          </exec> 
</target>
```

but it failed when running ANT:

```
Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ldap" (in directory "/etc/init.d"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

what is wrong with my ANT script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ended up with a solution myself:

```
<target name="ldap-service-start" description="Start LDAP service">
      <exec executable="/etc/init.d/ldap" osfamily="unix">
       <arg line="start"/>
      </exec> 
</target>
```